# Get selected Row in DataGrid and Change the background color

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

Whenever the user clicks a button I want to get the selected row in a DataGrid and change its background color?
I can get the index of the selected row using the SelectedIndex property but I do not know how to change the background of the same.

I use WPF, C# and .Net 4 in VS2010.

Thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's better to use triggers for this sort of things but try the following

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridRow dataGridRow = dataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(dataGrid.SelectedIndex) as DataGridRow;
    if (dataGridRow != null)
    {
        dataGridRow.Background = Brushes.Green;
    }
}
```

**Edit**
The selected `DataGridCells` will still override that background so you would probably have to handle that as well, using the `Tag` property on the parent `DataGridRow` for example

```
<DataGrid ...>
    <DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}},
                                               Path=Tag}" Value="ChangedBackground">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.CellStyle>
    <!--...-->
</DataGrid>

private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridRow dataGridRow = dataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(dataGrid.SelectedIndex) as DataGridRow;
    if (dataGridRow != null)
    {
        dataGridRow.Background = Brushes.Green;
        dataGridRow.Tag = "ChangedBackground";
    }
}
```

Comment: @Manoj: Good to hear :) Not sure if you needed the updated part but I added it just in case..

Comment: the same code i used but always return null with me any idea please

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
//get DataGridRow
DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)dGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(RowIndex);
row.Background = Brushes.Red;
```

Comment: It always return null with me any idea so please help

Comment: works very well! But is there another way to clear to default color?
I'm using a for loop that selects each rowIndex. :(

Answer (score 0):

DataGridRow has Background property. Is it what you need?

Answer (score 0):

you can also use this:

```
<DataGrid ...>
<DataGrid.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}},
                                           Path=IsSelected}" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.CellStyle>
<!--...-->
```

Comment: seems like a decent answer might be worth explaining what it is doing.